# Android ViewAnimator height changing base on child

Tags: java, android, viewanimator

By default, the max size of all children is used as the VeiwAnimator's layout size.
How to create ViewAnimator, which height changes depending on the size of displaying child?

Answer (score 13):

Either by specifying the `android:measureAllChildren="false"` as a ViewAnimator XML attribute or `viewAnimator.setMeasureAllChildren(false)` in code.

Comment: [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html#setMeasureAllChildren%28boolean%29) says "Defaults to false", but default was true! :|